# writing a script to process a sorted photos folder on photoshop CS6

Tags: javascript, database, photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

I'm trying to write a script for CS6 to process photos for a website. I have some experience in programing in Python and I looked at some Java scripts for CS6 and can understand the commands and logics.

I thought about this idea for a code.

I have a folder of the pictures, cleaned and after editing process, "Trimmed" of white areas from all sizes and sorted by their SKU which are unique. For example 123BLK1, 123BLK2, 123BLK3 etc..
The photos were taken from the same place in the same angles same lens and everything.
Think of an object that found in a the tightest white background possible by his lines.

I found out that after I take a series of pictures and find the longest or highest dimension of all series, If I open a square canvas in a size 5% bigger then the biggest dimension of all series, I get the series perfectly centered and with the right proportions between angles!!

My idea was to make a script that creates a sorted database out the files in the folder and save the biggest dimension out of the series and then open the square canvas in that dimension.
Like a dictionary database, that the cells will have the pictures names and the key will be the biggest dimension.
Then, for every picture series, open a square canvas in the size of the key.

For example, if I have these pictures in the folder, the dictionary will sort every 5 SKU with the same number and same color (different angle 1..5), save the biggest dimension in the key and open the square canvas for each series by it's key
SKU Width   Hight   Series Key
123BLK1 850 1200
123BLK2 1300 1400
123BLK3 1500 600
123BLK4 1900 900    1900
123BLK5 1100 1700
123GRY1 750 1000
123GRY2 900 1800    1800
123GRY3 1200 1500
123GRY4 1400 1300
123GRY5 1100 750

I'm might be wrong in something here, but if somebody understand my idea and can help me out with the code for a CS6 version I'll really appreciate it!

Thanks a lot!

Stav

Comment: Have you attempted to write any of this yourself? If so, can you post your code and tell us where you are struggling.  If not, there is scripting documentation in your photoshop installation directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Scripting\Documents). You'll get better answers if you attempt to have a go on your own first and come here when you have smaller, more manageable issues we can help you with.

Comment: Well as I said, I'm not familiar with the exact commands in JS but I can write the logic in words as I know that everything is similar between code languages, the For loops, saving variation etc.. 1. choose the path folder and put it in a var 2. create an empty dictionary that the key is an integer and the value is a list of strings 3. for

Comment: 3. for all files in the folder - check the file name, if the file name (without the last char) is found in the dict, then add it to a dict cell as a part of a list series, else put it in an empty cell in the dict (create a new series). 4. for a sorted dict, find the biggest dimension value for every series and save it as the series key in the dict. 5. for every series open a square white canvas in the size of the key for each file in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a code in Python. If somebody knows how to make it in JS for CS6 i'll reall appreciate it.

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter, ImageOps

def canvas (path):
    dic = {}
    for file in os.listdir( path ):
        if dic.get(file[:6]) == None:
            dic[file[:6]] = [file]
        else:
            dic[file[:6]]+=[file]
    for key in dic:
        dim = None
        for pic in dic[key]: # find biggest dimmention
            im = Image.open(path+pic)
            if dim < max(im.size):
                dim = max(im.size)
        for pic in dic[key]: # open square canvas
            im = Image.open(path+pic,'r')
            w,h = im.size
            background = Image.new('L', (dim,dim), "white")
            background.paste(im,((dim-w)/2,(dim-h)/2))
            background.save(path+pic)
```